# Get XML from python HttpResponse

Tags: javascript, python, html, xml, django

Is there any way how to GET xml data (via Javascript) from python HttpResponse and place it into body element on webpage?

There is example of my xml in python:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.Element("table")

tr = ET.SubElement(root, "tr")
td = ET.SubElement(tr, "td")
td.text = "some text"
tree = ET.ElementTree(root) 

response = HttpResponse(tree)
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.get("http://localhost:8000/getXml", function(data){
    alert(data);
  });      
});
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML is XML, so whatever HTML (partial, not full page i.e. no `<head>` or `<body>` tags) you return as HTTP response can be inserted in the webpage.

This is what ajax requests do.

Do you want to build the response using XML APIs? Although you can do that but django template s are much suitable for that. In any which way you build the response, get a string representation and return as response.

Comment: thanks, i just add:  resp = ET.tostring(root,encoding="us-ascii", method="html") and it works.

Comment: Not relevant to the question, but HTML is *not* XML. XHTML is XML, but other versions of HTML - including HTML5 - can be perfectly valid while being invalid XML.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Rohan that you should research Python if you're trying to serve data from Python to a web-client, or as a mixture of HTML/CSS/Javascript, or what have you. Check this [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/) out. It's awesome and only took me a few days to get through, and allows for a lot of different applications. The Onion, if you've ever heard of it apparently uses Django.